# What can be the reason behind the failure of setShowBadge(false)?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am posting a `notification` for a `background task` and bring it to `foreground` with `startForeground` with a visible `ongoing notification`. When it completes, I replace it with a `cancellable` notification using the same `notification id` and the same channel I created with `setShowBadge(false)`.

The scenario works correctly: It does not show badge for the ongoing task and it is successfully replaced with the `non-ongoing` version. Except, `setShowBadge(false)` does not work when I use it for the cancellable notification.

I checked the official sample and many examples and I also checked my code, I could not find any problems. So, there has to be an exceptional situation here. What can be the problem? What am I possibly missing here?

Comment: You might have overlooked something, can you show the code where both notifications are shown and channel is created?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir I added more information.

Comment: can you try calling `createChannel()` in `maeNotificationCancellable()` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir Unfortunately it did not work (it still shows the badge with text "1"). I also checked the return value of this and returns false correctly --> mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID).canShowBadge()

Comment: try going into settings menu of phone, I think user settings can override channel settings

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled my app and the same thing happens. I cannot tell users to go into settings and turn off notification badge of my app; it is not practical. If it is working for the first part of the notification, there has to be a way to make it work for the second time too :|

Comment: could it be that you are creating this notification channel elsewhere in your app as well?

Comment: I neither create channel nor post notification anywhere else :|

Comment: using any custom launcher?

Comment: That is correct, Microsoft Launcher and Evie Launcher showed it even though the system launcher is not showing it. So this is 3rd party launcher's mistake. Can't they support it or aren't they supporting it? ( it = setShowBadge(false) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on default launcher in use. Stock launcher will work as expected but **some launchers have their own implementation of Notification badges** and they've been using it since way before badges were supported officially. For those launchers, this flag won't work.

Even if the launchers use notification badges from channels, they might not care about this flag (like in your case). I would say try calling `setNumber(0)` and hope that it works.

```
 mNotificationBuilder.setNumber(0)
```

Comment: I tried setting setNumber on the notificationBuilder to 0 but that changed nothing. On the other hand, I tested other apps and they show badge on custom launchers too.. So it seems like I cannot do anything more. It looks like it is not my bad. ( I will award this answer in a few days if I don't come up with a surprise solution.)